# How to create a file for each line of text with File name as Field1, Field 2?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a file for each line of the text and want to assign name to the files in the following pattern.

For example:

File name: F001 inside data "text1".

File name: F001 inside data "text2".

Comment: I would like to suggest that your Question is still not clear to the readers that exactly what type of File you are suppose to create. Edit the body text and specify your real need.

Answer (score 0):

Below should help,
assume `source_file.txt` is the file with data.
    #!/bin/bash

```
while read -r line   
do   
  file_name=`echo $line | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1 | cut -d " " -f 1`   
  text=`echo $line | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1 | cut -d " " -f 2`   
  echo "creating $file_name with $text"   
  echo $text > $file_name   
done <source_file.txt
```

output will be something like below, and files will be created with data.
`creating F001 with "text1"
creating F002 with "text2"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming source_file.txt contains the data.

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
while read line
do
    counter=$((counter+1))
    echo $line > F${counter}
done < source_file.txt
```